# How to manage/ track changes to SQL Server database without compare tool

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, compare

I'm working on a project as an outsourcing developer where i don't have access to testing and production servers only the development environment.

To deploy changes i have to create sql scripts containing the changes to make on each server for the feature i wish to deploy.

**Examples:**

- When i make each change on the database, i save the script to a folder, but sometimes this is not enought because i sent a script to alter a view, but forgot to include new tables that i created in another feature.
- Another situation would be changing a table via SSMS GUI and forgot to create a script with the changed or new columns and later have to send a script to update the table in testing.

Since some features can be sent for testing and others straight to production (example: queries to feed excel files) its hard to keep track of what i have to send to each environment.

Since the deployment team just executes the scripts i sent them to update the database, how can i manage/ keep track of changes to sql server database without a compare tool ?

**[Edit]**

The current tools that i use are SSMS, VS 2008 Professional and TFS 2008.

Comment: When you say without a compare tool what do you mean?  Back when I was in a situation like yourself where I didn't have access to production servers I would simply keep a spreadsheet with a list of changes I've made.  I would also make sure that each change that required a script had one associated with it.  I just did that manually.  Without a tool to keep track of things for you, what else is there aside from doing it yourself?

Comment: I mean without tools like SQL Compare or SQL Data Compare from Red Gate since i don't have access to additional servers. I'm trying to keep track of changes but it's hard (IMHO) since you can send subsets of features to different environments. Tracking changes this way takes considerable time, i'm looking for a better way.

Comment: With SQL Compare you can compare the current version of a database schema with one from a backup, so you shouldn't actually need access to the testing or production servers

Comment: We don't have access to backups. Currently we work on a backup from production but has been updated by several developers before i even began to work on this project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look into Liquibase specially at the SQL format and see if that gives you what you want. I use it for our database and it's great.

You can store all your objects in separate scripts, but when you do a Liquibase "build" it will generate one SQL script with all your changes in it.  The really important part is getting your Liquibase configuration to put the objects in the correct dependency order. That is tables get created before foreign key constraints for one example.

http://www.liquibase.org/

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how we at xSQL Software do this using our tools:

- deployment team has an automated process that takes a schema snapshot of the staging and production databases and dumps the snapshots nightly on a share that the development team has access to.
- every morning the developers have up to date schema snapshots of the production and staging databases available. They use our [Schema Compare tool](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_schema_compare/) to compare the dev database with the staging/production snapshot and generate the change scripts.

Note: to take the schema snapshot you can either use the Schema Compare tool or our Schema Compare SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can have a structural copy of test and production servers as additional development databases and keep in mind to always apply change when you send something.

On these databases you can establish triggers that will capture all DDL events and put them into table with getdate() attached. With that you should be able to handle changes pretty easily and some simple compare will also be easier to apply.

Comment: We don't have access to backups. Unfortunatly the deployment team makes a huge fuss when a request for backup is made... unfrendly foes..